# php call function within heredoc

Tags: php, class, function, heredoc

I'm trying to call a function from within a heredoc, and I read in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) (example #2) that it is possible. However, I get the following error: `Notice: Undefined property: TIME::$since on line 13`.

```
1   <?php class TIME {
2       var $month;
3       var $year;
4       public function since($y) {
5           $this->$month = (date("F"));
6           $this->$year = (date("Y")-$y);
7           return "(since $month of $year)";
8           // return "(since date('F') of {date('Y')-$y})";
9       }
10  }
11  $time = new TIME;
12  echo <<<EOF
13      {$time->since{1}};
14  EOF; ?>
```

What I need to do is pass `1` as an integer to the function `since()` and return a string like `(since January of 2011)`.

Comment: since{1} should be since(1) - since it's a function call

Comment: Have you tried renaming your class, let's say to TimeSince ?

Comment: And if you try `{$time->since(1)}` instead of `{$time->since{1}}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your code. `$this->$month` and `$this->$year` must be `$this->month` and `$this->year` in your case, `return "(since $month of $year)";`, I think, must be `return "(since {$this->month} of {$this->year})";`, `{$time->since{1}};` may be `{$time->since(1)};`, and, finally, `EOF; ?>` - ending PHP tag must be on newline when closing heredoc:

```
EOF;
?>
```

P.S. Why are you using old, PHP4-style properties declaration?

Comment: Oh wow, that explains a lot ^^, thanks! btw, what do you mean "PHP4-style properties declaration"?

Comment: @jacob what timur is referencing to is this: `var $month;` check this: [PHP5 Variables Basics docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey, I don't normally do that, but since I was having trouble, I tried to follow the example on the page.

Comment: @jacob So, I think, you now have no need to use `var` keyword instead of `public` or something else :)

Answer (score 4):

It's `$time->since(1)`. Using `since{1}` is interpreted as "give me the 2nd character of the string stored in the $time object's attribute known as 'since'".

e.g:

```
$x = 'hello';
echo $x{0}; // outputs 'h'
echo $x{2}; // outputs 'l'
```

Answer (score 1):

everything works like expected, but your does not have a property `$since`, but a method `since()`. Just call it like a method

```
$time->since(1);
```

Here the `{1}` is the alternative syntax for array access.